# Inline style in react background: linear-gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make inline styles with a `background` that has a `linear-gradient` but the style is not being applied.

Here is my code:

```
 <div className="card" style={{background:"linear-gradient(to bottom, Transparente 0%,Transparente 50%,red 50%,red 100%)"}}/>
```

When I add "simple" color for my background, meaning no `linear-gradient`, it works well.

```
<div className="card" style={{background:"red"}}/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not `Transparente` color. Try `transparent`.

Comment: I agree with @GabrielePetrioli try: `linear-gradient(to bottom, Transparent 0%,Transparent 50%,red 50%,red 100%`

Answer (score 32):

I do not think you've written your code correctly. See examples of this site [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

```
<div className="card" style={{background: "linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);" }}>sada</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

use this code:

```
backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to right, #4880EC, #019CAD)"
```

Answer (score 11):

I had something like:

```
<div style={{background: `linear-gradient(190deg, #fa7c30 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)30%), url(${somePic});`}}/>
```

This was not working because of the `;` at the end of the `linear-gradient`. I removed it and it worked.

Comment: you're the real mvp

Answer (score 6):

Used like this with a variables

```
const color1 = "#343336";
const color2 = "#B408A4";
style={{background: `linear-gradient(to bottom,  ${color1} 0%,${color2} 100%)`}}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for react version 17.0.2, i used bacgroundImage property to style div background as follows:

   <div
    style={{
      backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(yellow,lightgreen)",
      color: "darkred",
    }}
  >
    Inline style in react background: linear-gradient
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

So, I came across your post because I was facing the same issue, but I've found a solution.

```
<button style={{ backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 224, 255, 1), rgba(0, 133, 255, 1))`, }} >
```

Note that I've used ` instead of ' which solved the issue, and tbh I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Iam a little bit late maybe, but I found a solution, what I did, I add it in css page, then inspect the element.
For example : for * background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%,  #000 50%, #fff 50% #fff 100%)*; if you inspect it using inspect element, you will find : *-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#000), color-stop(50%, #000), color-stop(50%, #fff))* .
So just add this last line in the inline style of your react compenent:

```
<div className="card" style={{background:"-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#000), color-stop(50%, #000), color-stop(50%, #fff))"}}/>
```

for my example, I used this one above instead of :

```
<div className="card" style={{background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%,  #000 50%, #fff 50% #fff 100%)"}}/>
```

So in conclusion, add this to a css file, it will work, see the output in the "inspect element", and use it and edit it as you like in the inline style of your react js component.

Answer (score 1):

> Please use Below code for adding the gradient and change the value (for Safari and Chrome)

```
-webkit-gradient: (linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2)));
```

Comment: It's a duplication of my response here below :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950627/inline-style-in-react-background-linear-gradient/59546630#59546630

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `transparent` with `Transparente`. This works: `linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%,transparent 50%,red 50%,red 100%)`

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do it inline this worked for me.

```
<Button style={{ backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(#f67a36,#ed008c)' }}/>
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe for gradient backgrounds you must use the background-image property.  So it should look something like this. You also have a typo with Transparent.

```html
 <div className="card" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, Transparent 0%,Transparent 50%,red 50%,red 100%)"></div>
```

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. Because inline style in `react` differs from inline `css class`. Your styling is written like inline `css class` format.